# Why does my custom 'actionBarTabStyle' not override the default style / theme?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-theme, android-styles

I've been trying for days now to override the Holo Theme for a custom Tab Style, but my changes don't have any effect.

Here's my styles.xml

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabs" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">

    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tabselector</item>
</style>>
```

This is my tabselector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

I've added the tabs using TabHost in my activity and its layout looks like this

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

I have followed the examples from the  [Android Developer Page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

My tabs still look the same.
My tab indicators are supposed to be my custom color of pink.  However, there is no change, they are still blue.

Things to note:

1. My manifest file references the updated theme in my application tags
2. My styles.xml is updated in each value folder (values, values-v11, values-v14)
3. All this did was add an action bar on top of my application with my ic_launcher image and title

What am I missing or doing wrong?  Appreciate any help. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tabs in the `ActionBar` use a different theme than the tabs in `TabHost`.

All you need to do is change `android:actionBarTabStyle` to `android:tabWidgetStyle`.

**Full example**

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/Your.TabWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.TabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.TabWidget">
    <item name="*android:tabLayout">@layout/your_tab_layout</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.Tab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">80dip</item>
</style>
```

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Your.Tab"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxWidth="180dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Although, `android:tabLayout` isn't a public attribute (hence the *). Google wouldn't recommend creating the style like that because of this and instead would suggest modifying the indicator dynamically. So, something like this:

```
    final TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
    for (int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getTabCount(); i++) {
        final View tab = tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(i);
        tab.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_tab_indicator));
    }
```

**Results**

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Did that. It definitely changed something with the hairline underneath the tabs... However, the blue indicator color is still there.  I think I can see the pink hiding underneath the blue... but its still overlapping.

Comment: Updated my code in style.xml to display the edit in your suggestion

Comment: It worked! Dynamically changing the tab indicator using my tabselector.xml in my mainactivity.java file where the tabs are created.  Thanks @adneal :)

Comment: @adneal how did you know about that solution? Can I somehow learn how inspect that things?